# How to get the node value from xml using PowerShell script?

Tags: xml, powershell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="MultipleSuite">
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="samplexml_1.xml"></suite-file>
</suite-files>
</suite>
<!-- Suite -->
```

here how to get the 'samplexml_1.xml' name ?

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath and [the `Select-Xml` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-6):

```
$suite_file = Select-Xml "//suite-file" yourfile.xml
```

This selects an array of `<suite-file>` nodes (in your example, there is only one match). You can access the result like this:

```
$suite_file.Node.path
```

prints

```
samplexml_1.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Get content of xml file to `[xml]` type variable. Like so:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content file.xml
$xml.suite.'suite-files'.'suite-file'.path
#samplexml_1.xml
```

Comment: Don't do `[xml]$xml = Get-Content file.xml`. This will break the data when the file is not in the encoding `Get-Content` expects. `$xml = New-Object xml; $xml.Load("file.xml")` is *much* better, because this uses the encoding detection of the XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

This would work but is probably not the best solution depending on what you want to achieve at the end.

```
$xml = [xml]'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="MultipleSuite">
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="samplexml_1.xml"></suite-file>
</suite-files>
</suite>'

$xml.suite."suite-files"."suite-file".path
```